# Appcelerator Menu in Container view

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

i'm looking for creating a menu on both platform in a container view. But i can't find anything about this here or on the doc.
Look like i need to create a window or something like that but i can't do this or maybe i didn't understand how it works.
My company asked me to update this app but i never worked on appcelerator before, so i'm pretty confused..

If someone can take time to explain me what to do or what to search :)

Thanks !

Here is the file where i'm trying to add a menu, as you can see i added a label, but i don't think it's that good ^^

```
exports.createView = function(args){
 args = args || {};
 var specialStyle = _.extend({
    backgroundColor: '#35363a'
    , height: Alloy.isHandheld ? 50 : 100
    , width: Ti.UI.FILL
    , top: OS_IOS ? /*(Alloy.isHandheld ? 25 : 50)*/ /* */ 22 /* */ : 0
    , left : 0
}, args);

// On crée le cadre
var headerView = Ti.UI.createView(specialStyle);


var containerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:Ti.UI.FILL
    , height: Ti.UI.FILL
    , top: 0
    , left:0
    , layout: 'horizontal'
    , zIndex: 10
});
headerView.add(containerView);

// Ajout du bouton pour quitter
var labelQuit;
containerView.add(labelQuit = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
    , width: '13%'
    , backgroundColor: "red"
    , font: {
        fontFamily:'nepting'
        , fontSize:Alloy.isHandheld ? 17 : 34
    }
    , text : ''
    , color:  '#fff'
    , top : 0
    , left: 0
    , textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    , isLabelQuitApp : true
}));

// Espace pour le nom de l'utilisateur
containerView.add(Ti.UI.createView({
    width:'5%'
    , left: 0
}));


// Utilisateur connecté, sur le header view principal
var labelUser;
headerView.add(labelUser = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
    , height: Ti.UI.FILL
    , top: 0
    , left: 0
    , text : Alloy.Globals.connectionInfo.userLogin || 'UTILISATEUR Dummy'
    , color: '#ccc'
    , font: {
        fontSize: Alloy.isHandheld ? 12 : 24,
        fontFamily: 'DINOT-Light'
    }
    , textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
    , zIndex: 2
}));
// Logo de la marque paramétrée
var imageCustomLogo, customLogoView;

// Ajout de la vue du logo personnalisé au conteneur
containerView.add(customLogoView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '50%'
    , backgroundColor: "green"
    , left: 0
    , height: Ti.UI.FILL
    , textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
}));

// Ajout de l'image
customLogoView.add(imageCustomLogo = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : '/images/customLogo.png'
    , width: '70%'
  //, height: Alloy.isHandheld ? 42 : 84
}));

var menu;
containerView.add(menu = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
    , width: '12%'
    , top: '40%'
    , backgroundColor: "purple"
    , font: {
        fontFamily:'nepting'
        , fontSize:Alloy.isHandheld ? 17 : 34
    }
    , text : ''
    , color:  '#fff'
    , top : 0
    , left: 0
    , textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
}));

// On retourne le cadre du header
return headerView;
```

};

Comment: I'm assuming you want a custom menu? Talk to me on http://TiSlack.org to help you, this seems too specific for Stackoverflow anyways

Comment: Ok, i'm coming. Thanks for your help :)